# Get location ( BroadcastReceiver,LocationListener)

Tags: android, sms, location, broadcastreceiver, locationlistener

I am beginner at android. I have a question. I want to when I receive SMS then get my location(latitude and longitude). How can I do.
if you have sample code, it will be more helpful.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You will have to write a broadcast receiver for Action - RECEIVE_SMS. In that you will have to implement LocationListener class and access location from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer [this example](http://mansivora.blogspot.in/2011/03/google-map-give-current-location-as.html). I hope it helps you.

In this example the current location will be display and touched location will also display with lat-lon.

Answer (score 4):

For getting latitude and longitude when you have recived an sms on device you will need these steps:

**STEP 1:**
Register an `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` BroadcastReceiver for receiving incoming sms notification:

for this you can use following Tutorial :

http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/receiving-sms-using-broadcastreceiver.html

---

**STEP 2:**

for retrieving location on sms received you will need to start an service (`IntentService`) in onReceive of SMS BroadcastReceiver as:

```
public class SmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

 private static final String TAG = "Message recieved";

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
      // Start your Location IntentService here 
             Intent i = new Intent(context, Location_Intent_Service.class);
            context.startService(i);
    }
 }

}
```

---

For How We use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) you can see following tutorial:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/

---

For how we Use [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) from Service class you can follow these Post:

[Starting LocationManager as Service Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672736/starting-locationmanager-as-service-android)

Comment: sure if you have any question related to this answer then you will leave  comment  to me.Thank !!:)